# При клонировании Git репозитория перестаёт работать синхронизация

Tags: visual-studio, git, visual-studio-2015

Последовательность была следующая..

cd     /TestGit

mkdir  my_test_git.git

cd     my_test-git.git

git init --bare

Далее в VS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том теперь, что если я папку с проектом просто скопирую (Ctl+c), то синхронизация работает и все ОК. Но если клонирую репозиторий, то всё перестаёт работать. Как сделать так, чтобы было по человечески, а не Ctrl+c Ctrl+v.

Общая задумка была в том, чтобы разработчики подключались по rdp к собственному серверу и там работали над одним проектом.

Заранее спасибо, жду ваших предложений по этому поводу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что Вы хотите использовать голый (bare) репозиторий на своей машине и что бы студия с ним работала?

Comment: Не совсем вопрос понял. Студия с ним работает, она работает если я папку с проектом просто копирую в разные места.(фиксацию могу отправить), а если делаю $ git clone, то отправить фиксации не могу.

Comment: Может я что-то делаю совсем не так?

Comment: Есть удаленный сервер, есть проект. Задача настроить Git для совместной разработки без использования GitHub и т.д.

Comment: очень сложно понять, что именно Вы делаете и как именно Вы настроили подключение (вы же поскрывали). Но если почитаете текст ошибки, то оно как раз и говорит о том, что пушить в не bare репозиторий нельзя.  Я бы взял https://gitea.io/ и сделал бы красиво и хорошо (если что - там даже устанавливать ничего не нужно. А выглядеть будет как домашний гитхаб/гитлаб.

Comment: Там путь такой: W:\Elmar_folders\GIT_SERVER\Test1.git